# Is There a Way to Edit a Text File After It Is Created in Java?

Tags: java

I know how to create files using Java, but my question is can I edit the file later?
For Example:Can I make a .txt file with log in Information and every time a new user signs up the .txt file updates itself and adds the new information without modifying the old one.

Comment: Beware of multi-threading issues.  You should use Logback.

Comment: @SLaks: Logback? Edit: ah, link: [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).